# How to Renaming a Project or App in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode6, project, rename

I want to rename my exiting iOS project in xcode. I have already used following steps for this.

I have used xcode 6.4 version.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH21

But after click on rename, It is change from iOS to My Mac and I am not able to run this project in iOS simulator.
Debug and Run is disable after rename the project. see attached screenshot.

So, Please help me.
How to Renaming a Project ?

[image]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: check your target on project settings also scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your scheme you did not define your renamed project name...

goto `edit scheme->Debug`, if there is any red colored missing files...add new by plus button at the end of panel...and same check for test and then

goto `edit scheme->Run->executable` and select your renamed app name.

Comment: I have apply your solution and after that try to run or debug its error. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: but now you have target to run and its run too...but its another error for you...the solution I gave is for the target instead of display mac....and its working right?now for this error you have to check your log....